# Fetching Data from RecyclerView and performing calculations on it

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I created a RecyclerView with cardview of linearlayout, and this RecyclerView fetches data from firebase real-time database. My RecyclerView looks as follows

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZB7dV.png

Now, in the price section of the activity, I want to add the total price of all the views. But, I am not able to do that.

I tried adding the item-price in `populateviewholder` method using the sum variable, but every time I scroll by RecyclerView the value sum changes, even if I have not added any extra item.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3PSJ.png

Please suggest a way, to calculate the total of all the prices of views in RecyclerView and then display it in the total section.

### The red bar with text total is not the part of RecyclerView.

Comment: you could not execute de sum on populate Views, recyclerView do not pass all items, you have to register to ObservableSnapshotArray passed to your FirebaseRecyclerOptions  and calculate the sum on dataChanged or you can execute another query to retrieve the sum...

Answer (score 1):

Take a variable sum and a list which will hold the product names,in onBindViewHolder method, view gets created, so first check whether product is exist in the list if not then add the product in list and add price in sum variable.